# Inno Setup installing prerequisites

Tags: mongodb, inno-setup

I am creating an installer through Inno Setup. I see a lot of code examples on how to detect a prerequisite's existence, but nothing on how to actually go about installing the prerequisite when I don't find it. I'm sure it's blindingly simple, but how do I go about installing a prerequisite? In particular, I'm looking to install `mongodb` as a service as a prerequisite to my application.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [CodePrepareToInstall.iss](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodePrepareToInstall.iss) example script (included with Inno) for the framework.  Once you've detected that you need to do the install, at the appropriate point (shown in the script) you just `ExtractTemporaryFile` the installer for the prerequisite and then `Exec` it, checking for any errors and reboot-required-before-main-app-install conditions as needed.

For a more in-depth example for several common prerequisites (including download support), see [this page](http://tonaday.blogspot.co.nz/2011/01/inno-setup-preparetoinstall-scripts.html).

Comment: @TLama, as the questioner clearly states "`mongodb` as a service as a prerequisite", it is obvious that detecting the presence of the service is enough and he/she is already aware of that. The question scope is just "how to install mongodb as service in Inno Setup".